# Javascript String Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm using Jquery for DOM manipulation, and I'm finding it invaluable.

Is there a similar library for strings?

I find myself needing to do manipulations and running selectors on parts of strings, and I just wish I can apply jquery syntax to it.

Anyone know of anything like that?

Ideally I would use a syntax like this:

```
var select = $(\regexmatch\)    
$(select:last:not(:last-child)).after("sometext").wrap("<wrapper></wrapper>");
```

Edit: If the answer is, there is no such thing, that's fine too.

However, does anyone know if it's possible to write custom jquery selectors that would work on strings in this fashion.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by jQuery syntax, but what's wrong with RegExp? How much higher level would you want such a library to be?

Comment: You need to bone up on your regular expression syntax. They are more powerfull. String procesing does not lend itself to a node based selection idiom. This is why you don't see it done.

Comment: I think you want some... sugar methods for what would otherwise be plain RegExp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to do powerful matching and replacements in strings. It's completely different from JQuery selectors as it's not based on CSS, but it's more powerful.

For example, put a span tag around all occurances of a word:

```
s = s.replace(/stackoverflow/g, '<span class="Found">$1</span>');
```